# parse function not getting called in Scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm using scrapy + selenium stack for crawling task. I have worked with them before, the following technique worked fine. But now, my `parse` function is not getting called. Following is my code snippet

```
class CancerForumSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mainpage_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["cancerforums.net"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.cancerforums.net/forums/14-Prostate-Cancer-Forum"
    ]
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        print("----------------inside init----------------")

    def __exit__(self):
        print "------------Exiting----------"
        self.browser.quit()

    def parse(self,response):
        print "----------------Inside Parse------------------"
        log.start()
```

When I run the crawler, it just prints `inside init` and print statement inside parse doesn't work. I have earlier followed same method and it was working. Can pointers as to what I might be missing ?

Comment: Try changing your User-Agent, with `USER_AGENT` setting. Something like "Mozilla" worked for me.

Comment: Have you tried changing the user agent? With the defaut user agent, the spider did not get pages back

Comment: Hey, changing the  `USER_AGENT` to the latest Mozilla setting worked. But I still don't understand how/why this setting was blocking the execution of parse function

Comment: The webserver is not returning any data with scrapy's User-Agent. If you let the crawler run long enough, enough for the download timeout to fire, you'd see the requests fail. You can test with `scrapy crawl <spider> -s DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT=5` for example

Comment: yeah, that makes sense. Thanks.